# building a function which calculate elements of several vectors

Tags: r

The input contains 3 vectors (X, R, N)
I want to create a new vector that for each element do a calculation using the corresponding elements in vectors X, R, N, the calculation is X*(1+R/100)^N
I tried:

```
q4 = function(X, R, N) {

  tot <- X*(1+R/100)^N

}
```

but it did nothing...
This is just example' I want to know how to create new vector by manipulating elements of other vectors
Thank you

Comment: `return(tot)` at the end of the function maybe?

Comment: @RLave Or just `tot`. Or even more simply, just don't assign the result to `tot`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: You should tell us more about your expected output by showing an example for us.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine as long as you remember to return the output.

```
q4 <-  function(X, R, N) {
  tot <- X*(1+R/100)^N
  tot
}

X <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9)
R <- c(3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 2)
N <- c(8, 7, 5, 4, 5, 1)

q4(X, R, N)
# 1.266770  3.947795  5.352902  7.864776 10.770368  9.180000
```

In R you can return a a value using `return()`. This is handy if you have a conditional statement and one condition lets you return the value early, but in most cases just calling the object you want returned is sufficient.

Let me demonstrate.

```
q5 <-  function(X, R, N) {
  if (missing(N)) {
    return(X*(1+R/100))
  }
  tot <- X*(1+R/100)^N
  tot
}

q5(X, R)
# 1.03 3.12 4.24 6.42 7.63 9.18
```

Things after `return()` won't be evaluated, things after `tot` will.

```
q6 <-  function(X, R, N) {
  if (missing(N)) {
    return(X*(1+R/100))
    1 + 2
  }
  tot <- X*(1+R/100)^N
  tot
  1 + 2
}

q6(X, R)
# 1.03 3.12 4.24 6.42 7.63 9.18

q6(X, R, N)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine, as was mentioned above, even without `return`. In former case, however, it returns *last result* silently, without printing it to the console:

```
q4 = function(X, R, N) {
  tot <- X*(1+R/100)^N
}

set.seed(53260330)
x <- 1:10; y = 10:1; z = runif(10, 0, 10)

q4(x, y, z)

print(q4(x, y, z))
# [1] 1.843725  3.982180  3.230178  5.302991  6.178926  8.562266  ...

res <- q4(x, y, z)
res
# [1]  1.843725  3.982180  3.230178  5.302991  6.178926  8.562266  ...
```

Compare to the same function but with return:

```
q4_1 = function(X, R, N) {
  return(X*(1+R/100)^N)
}

q4_1(x, y, z)
# [1]  1.843725  3.982180  3.230178  5.302991  6.178926  8.562266  ...
```

My personal opinion: use `return` in the body of your function, if not for readability, than at least in order to avoid such unpleasant experience when function seems to return nothing, but only because it doesn't bother to print it's own output.